# jQuery .live() causing parallel loop

Tags: jquery

Let's get down to it; Click an AJAX-inserted LI element, popup a dialog box with a text input, when the input is above 100, submit the information for verification against the server. Here's what it looks like:

```
$("li").live("click", function() { 
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
    $("#pin").focus();
    $("#pin").keyup(function() {
        var trigger = $("#pin").val;            
        if (trigger > 100) { // Submit for verification, otherwise do nothing }
        }
    });
```

The issue that I'm running into is that it will function normally the first time. When an LI element is clicked again, the keyup function is running twice. If it is clicked again, it runs three times. Here's what the console dump looks like:

First Click:
1
10
100

Second Click:
1
1
10
10
100
100

Third:
1
1
1
10
10
10
100
100
100

Any thoughts would be really appreciated. If I'm injecting my AJAX incorrectly, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue is you keep adding an event handler to the #pin element. So the first time only a single handler is attached. The second time two handler and so on.

Move you $("#pin").keyup outside of the click handler.

Comment: Thank you so much Josh. That was it; I'd vote you up, but I can't login. It makes perfect sense now.

Comment: My pleasure glad I was able to help:-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .live was removed on 1.9.  Here's the correct way to do it:

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead. To exactly match $("a.foo").live("click", fn), for example,
>   you can write $(document).on("click", "a.foo", fn). For more
>   information, see the .on() documentation. In the meantime, the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin can be used to restore the .live() functionality.

Via http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed